# Drawing portion of bitmap in Android?

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have here a method to draw a rotated scaled bitmap in Android:

```
public void drawRotatedScaledBitmap(Bitmap b, 
        float centerX, float centerY, float width, float height, float angle)
{
    float scaleX = width / b.getWidth();
    float scaleY = height / b.getHeight();
    centerX -= (b.getWidth() * scaleX) / 2.0f;
    centerY -= (b.getHeight() * scaleY) / 2.0f;
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.setTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    matrix.postRotate(angle * (180.0f / (float)(Math.PI)),
            centerX + (b.getWidth() * scaleX) / 2.0f,
            centerY + (b.getHeight() * scaleY) / 2.0f); 
    matrix.preScale(scaleX,scaleY);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, matrix, null);
}
```

I'm not sure how I could modify this to take in float sourceX, float sourceY, float sourceW, float sourceH.

I want to render tile sets so I need to tell it say 64,64,64,64 on the bitmap.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
public void drawRotatedScaledBitmap(Bitmap b, 
        float centerX, float centerY, float width, float height,
        float sourceX, float sourceY, 
        float sourceWidth, float sourceHeight, float angle)
{
    float cx = centerX;
    float cy = centerY;

    dstRect.left = (int)centerX - (int)(width / 2);
    dstRect.top = (int)centerY - (int)(height / 2);
    dstRect.right = dstRect.left +  (int)width;
    dstRect.bottom = dstRect.top +  (int)height;

    srcRect.left = (int)sourceX;
    srcRect.top = (int)sourceY;
    srcRect.right = srcRect.left +  (int)sourceWidth;
    srcRect.bottom = srcRect.top +  (int)sourceHeight;

    canvas.rotate(angle * (180.0f / (float)(Math.PI)),cx,cy);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, srcRect, dstRect, null);
    canvas.rotate(-angle * (180.0f / (float)(Math.PI)),cx,cy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try canvas.clipRect() to specify the drawing area.

Comment: Android has a drawBitmap(source rect, dest rect) so it must be possible.

Comment: Can you rotate the canvas instead of rotating the bitmap? Then you can use drawBitmap(source rect, dest rect) to draw a portion of the bitmap  with a rotation angle.

Comment: Yes, I can do canvas.rotate, but I dont know how to  properly transform the canvas.